# JXcore, How external process monitoring works?

Tags: node.js, monitoring, jxcore

I am a newbie and trying to figure out how process monitoring works with JXcore. I saw the documentation but need few steps in order to make my server application starting multithreaded and monitored properly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to explain it to you. There is no shame to be a newbie! :)

JXcore offers you two types of application monitoring.

1) One of them is **Process Monitor** and this is a process, which runs as separate instance. Your applications may subscribe to it for being monitored. Monitor verifies them in regular intervals, and if it finds that your application is gone it tries to relaunch it. For example, if your application servers http and should be online all the time - Process Monitor will ensure, that it is really running.

The fastest way to start to monitor your application is to:

1. launch the monitor: `> jx monitor start`
2. launch your application with automatic subscription to the monitor: `> jx monitor run app.js`

After that, when your application crashes, Process Monitor will restart it. You can test it by just killing your application's process.

Process monitor also gives you information about currently monitored processes. You can browse to see the list of them:

```
http://127.0.0.1:17777/json
```

2) Second type of a monitoring feature is **process and thread recovery**. With **Process Recovery** you can achieve the same as with the Process Monitoring, so there is no reason to use them both at the same time.

Another scenario could be:

Let's say you have a multithreaded application and only to recovering it's threads is enough.

Your application is launched with a command:

> jx mt-keep:3 app.js

which means, that you run it with 3 threads.

To enable Thread Recovery is enough to subscribe to `process.on('restart')` event like this:

```
process.on('restart', function (cb) {
    process.release();
    cb();
});
```

Remember, to call `cb()` callback. As you probably saw it in the docs, the thread will not restart until you invoke this callback. Before restart, you may back-up things etc.

Basically that's it. Feel free to play with it!